# Spring Servlet 3.0 Async Controllers - what thread handles response?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat

I'm fairly new to Java (I'm using Java SE 7) and the JVM and trying to write an asynchronous controller using:

- Tomcat 7
- Spring MVC 4.1.1
- Spring Servlet 3.0

I have a component that my controller is delegating some work to that has an asynchronous portion and returns a ListenableFuture. Ideally, I'd like to free up the thread that initially handles the controller response as I'm waiting for the async operation to return, hence the desire for an async controller.

I'm looking at returning a DeferredResponse -- it seems pretty easy to bridge this with ListenableFuture -- but I can't seem to find any resources that explain how the response is delivered back to the client once the DeferredResponse resolves.

Maybe I'm not fully grok'ing how an asynchronous controller is supposed to work, but could someone explain how the response gets returned to the client once the DeferredResponse resolves? There has to be some thread that picks up the job of sending the response, right?

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Spring's DeferredResponse to excellent effect in a long-polling situation that I recently coded. Focusing on the 'how' of the response getting back to the user is, I believe, not the correct way to think about the object. Depending upon where it's used, it returns messages to the user in exactly the same way as a regular, synchronous call would only in a delayed, asynchronous manner. Again, the object does not define nor propose a delivery mechanism. Just a way to 'insert' an asynchronous response into existing channels.

Per your query, yes, it does so by creating a thread that has a timeout of the user's specification. If the code completes before the timeout, using 'setResult', the object returns the code's result. Otherwise, if the timeout fires before the result, the default, also set by the user, is returned. Either way, the object does not return anything (other than the object itself) until one of these mechanisms is called. Also, the object has to then be discarded as it cannot be reused.

In my case, I was using a HTTP request/response function that would wrap the returned response in a DeferredResponse object that would provide a default response - asking for another packet from client so the browser would not time out - if the computation the code was working on did not return before the timeout. Whenever the computation was complete, it would send the response via the 'setResult' function call. In this situation both cases would simply use the HTTP response to send a packet back to the user. However, in neither case would the response go back to the user immediately.

In practice the object worked flawlessly and allowed me to implement an effective long-polling mechanism.

Here is a snippet of the code in my example:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/text")
@ResponseBody
// public DeferredResult<String> onMessage(@RequestBody String message, HttpSession session) {
public DeferredResult<String> onMessage(InputStream is, HttpSession session) {
    String message = convertStreamToString(is);
    // HttpSession session = null;
    messageInfo info = getMessageInfo(message);
    String state = info.getState();
    String id = info.getCallID();

    DeferredResult<String> futureMessage =
            new DeferredResult<>(refreshIntervalSecs * msInSec, getRefreshJsonMessage(id));
    if(state != null && id != null) {
        if(state.equals("REFRESH")) {
            // Cache response for future and "swallow" call as it is restocking call
            LOG.info("Refresh received for call " + id);
            synchronized (lock) {
                boolean isReplaceable = callsMap.containsKey(id) && callsMap.get(id).isSetOrExpired();
                if (isReplaceable)
                    callsMap.put(id, futureMessage);
                else {
                    LOG.warning("Refresh packet arrived on a non-existent call");
                    futureMessage.setResult(getExitJsonMessage(id));
                }
            }
        } else if (state.equals("NEW")){
            // Store response for future and pass the call onto the processing logic
            LOG.info("New long-poll call received with id " + id);
            ClientSupport cs = clientSupportMap.get(session.getId());
            if(cs == null) {
                cs = new ClientSupport(this, session.getId());
                clientSupportMap.put(session.getId(), cs);
            }
            callsMap.put(id, futureMessage);
            // *** IMPORTANT ****
            // This method sets up a separate thread to do work
            cs.newCall(message);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.warning("Invalid call information");
        // Return value immediately when return is called
        futureMessage.setResult("");
    }
    return futureMessage;
}
```